# AUC for ROC curve in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand how the ROC curve works for AUC.

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X2)
probs = clf.predict_proba(X2)
# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
probs = probs[:, 1]
# calculate AUC
auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, probs)
```

When i ran `probs = probs[:,1]` i got an AUC of 0.66. However when i ran `probs=probs[:,0]` i got an AUC of 0.34.

I am working off a binary class problem.

The confusion matrix is as follows

```
array([[  77,   34],
       [ 825, 1027]])
```

My confusion is here that why the documentation states that we would have to use a greater class. What does the term greater class mean. If i were to swap the labels around doesnt it matter?

Extracted from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)

> For binary y_true, y_score is supposed to be the score of the class
>   with greater label.

Answer (score 2):

`score of the class with greater label` means that the scores should be for the class, which is represented as 1 (greater index).

If the input is multi-label type, then scores should have dimension as the y. Remember y has to converted into one hot or multi hot vector before feeding into `roc_auc_score`.

That is the reason for lower score, when you had given the 1st column of `proba` value, which represents the probability of class 0.